# How do I remove the untitled layer from my layer list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arcgis

I am creating a web application using html, CSS and JavaScript, specifically arcgis JavaScript API. I have created a layer list so that users can turn on and turn off the specific layers they want. However, there is a untitled layer and I am not sure where it is. When I try to turn it off from the layer list nothing moves from the map which suggests there is no data to toggle on or off. I have done weeks of debugging and I am getting nowhere so I would really appreciate some help. The screenshot showing the exact issue is below.

[image]

My code for the layer list looks like this:

```
view.when(() => {
  const layerList = new LayerList({
      view: view,
      visible: false,
      selectionEnabled: true
  });
  const expand = new Expand({
      view: view,
      content: layerList
  });

  // Add widget to the top right corner of the view
  view.ui.add(expand, "top-left");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more detail? Maybe working codepen?

Your JS is ok. Looks like someone along the way actually created a map layer named "Untitle Layer". That being the case you can use the [listItemCreatedFunction](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-LayerList.html#listItemCreatedFunction) in the [ListItemPanel widget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-LayerList-ListItemPanel.html) to make sure that specific item is not rendered.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I saw on another platform that i could include: {

    listMode: "hide";

} and it removed the untitled layer. Thank you